# FastCV Java installer failing due to InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android, computer-vision, macos-sierra, fastcv

I am trying to install FastCV SDK for use with Android Studio, but the installer applet which quallcomm provide will not even run. If I simply double click the .app file, the icon appears quickly then closes instantly.

If I open the package contents and run the file via terminal, I can get to an installer dialogue, which immediately shows an error and closes.

I have tried installing a newer version of JDK (9), but this has done nothing to alieviate the issue.

Is this a problem with MacOsX Sierra, or the FastCV installer? Is there a way for me to check that the version of Java I have is working correctly on this OS to try and resolve this issue?

Output error shown below.

Thanks

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/mrj/MRJFileUtils
at Flexeraand.aa(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.magicfolders.MacOSXDockMF.aa(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.magicfolders.MagicFolder.initializeAllMagicFolderPaths(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a3(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a0(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.mrj.MRJFileUtils
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
... 13 more
```